# Adding line to ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two continuous variables x and y, and I need to plot the points in different colors according to a third factor variable called DIAGNOSI (that is, according to the disease group these observations belong) and used this:

```
m<-qplot ( 
  x = Qalb, 
  y = Kratio,
  data = dataset,
  color = dataset$DIAGNOSI 
)
```

Then, there is an index whose optimal cutoff has been identified in 2.43, and this index is equal to y/x, so i need to add to the plot a line showing where this threshold is
How can i add this line?

Comment: ?abline could help

Comment: @joel.wilson Not in ggplot it won't, maybe you meant `geom_abline()`?

Comment: Here is a rough example: `qplot(x=1:20, y=(2.4 * 1:20 + rnorm(20))) + geom_abline(slope=2.4)`. There is also an intercept argument if that is needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
+geom_abline(dataset , aes(x=Qalb, y=Kratio), intercept = 2.43)
```